# How to download and install Code Rocket for Eclipse in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I'm using this link: http://www.rapidqualitysystems.com/updates/CodeRocketForEclipse/

But I can download an .exe installation and I'm using Ubuntu 14.04!

How or where can I download and install the package for Code Rocket in Eclipse for linux ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The System Requirements listed for CodeRocket for Eclipse [see here](http://www.rapidqualitysystems.com/Products/CodeRocketForEclipse) (near the bottom of the page) say it is for Windows only.

Comment: Thank you for the information. Can you recommend any tools or software for Ubuntu that can help my understanding of c++ in flowchart diagrams ?

Comment: For software recommendations you can ask on http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ but be sure to [provide enough information](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information)